# Get actual page and the last page from an URL with JSOUP

Tags: java, html, pagination, jsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to get the actual page and the last page, anybody can help me?

My code:

```
public void conectarSite(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        page = Jsoup.connect(url).data("query", "Java").userAgent("Agent").cookie("auth", "token").timeout(3000).post();
        
        
        //get actual Page
        Elements ActualPa=page.getElementsByClass("page active");
    
                        
        //get last Page
        Elements nextPage=page.getElementsByClass("page");
        int numPaginas =Integer.parseInt(nextPage.attr("#"));
                
    
    }
```

For the last page, with this code, I get "0" .
In attachment I am sending a print screen of HTML code. As you can see, the actual page is in the class "page active" and the current value is "1", for the last page the value is "16". [image: html printscreen]

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Useful: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax (lower down the page)

I've taken the liberty to type out a more basic string for the HTML but...
You could do it with something like:

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class PageExtraction {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String url = "<ul>"
                + "<li class=\"prev\">"
                +   "<a href=\"#\"><</a>"
                + "</li>"
                + "<li class=\"page active\">"
                +   "<a href=\"#\">1</a>"
                + "</li>"
                + "<li class=\"page\">2</li>"
                + "<li class=\"page\">3</li>"
                + "<li class=\"page\">4</li>"
                + "<li class=\"page\">5</li>"
                + "<li class=\"page\">6</li>"
                + "<li class=\"page\">...</li>"
                + "<li class=\"page\">"
                +   "<a href=\"#\">16</a>"
                + "</li>"
                + "</ul>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);
        String activePage = doc.select("[class=page active] a").text(); // elements with class "page active"
        String allPages = doc.select("li.page a").last().text(); // list elements with class page

        // TODO what if last page > some max threshold?
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is perfect! However i can't get the elements of the active page to String, I am using this selector to get elements 
`code`
String url = "https://www.auchan.pt/Frontoffice/search/frango";
Document page = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Agent").get();

Elements test=page.select(" #DivWrapperProductItem > div:nth-child(6) > ul > li.page.active");
`code`
However the return is nothing.

I am searching in this url " https://www.auchan.pt/Frontoffice/search/frango".

The idea was get with the elements and save to a String and use your code to extract from a String the active page!

Comment: I tried your code. If you try to access the url with no cookies set, you get an HTTP redirect (302) response to a login page which sets some cookies that your browser will remember. These track the user-session. Because of this you need to do some initial HTTP requests to record those cookies like your browser would normally do. Since I do a fair bit of screen scraping I already have some code to help with this. I'll drop a solution in the next comment. I would suggest using HtmlUnit if you're not stuck on using JSoup as it uses XPath for fetching data which is a better standard to learn & use

Comment: annoyingly I tried to get this working with JSoup and it seems impossible. I can do the exact same curl request and its fine. But with JSoup it fails each and every time. All I can suggest now is to use HtmlUnit instead OR you can try to reconstruct the HTTP GET requests made here: https://www.auchan.pt/Frontoffice/Scripts/bundle.min.js which you'll find by searching for `url: rootUrl +` in the script contents and work backwards. Use RestTemplate to make requests (hint: use method `restTemplate.exchange(url, headers, null, String.class)` replace in the headers/url with relevant ones

Comment: if you try to reconstruct the http GET request(s) I imagine you'll need some HTTP knowledge as well to reconstruct the requests using some hidden form fields that are there to prevent cross site forgery requests (CSRF tokens).

Comment: Thank you very much @Rob Evans! I resolved with an alternative way.